# Automate Cross region copying tables in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I have tables in a cluster at region-1 and I want to copy some of those tables in another cluster at some other region (region-2).

Till now I have used matillion and for that I have followed following steps-

1. Copy data to s3 from cluster-a.
2. Load this data from s3 to cluster-b.

Since matillion is a little bit costly for me to do work, and I want to have an alternative solution for this.

Although I have heard about CLI, Lambda and API but I am having no idea for how should I use these, since I go through this procedure on weekly basis and I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is not relevant for this use-case, because it is used to control AWS services (eg launch an Amazon Redshift database, change security settings). The commands to import/export data to/from Amazon Redshift must be issued to Redshift directly via SQL.

To copy some tables to an Amazon Redshift instance in another region:

- Use an [`UNLOAD` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html) in **Cluster A** to export data from Redshift to an Amazon S3 bucket
- Use a [`COPY` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) in **Cluster B** to load data from S3 into Redshift, using the `REGION` parameter to specify the source region

You will therefore need separate SQL connections to each cluster. Any program that can connect to Redshift via **JDBC** would suffice. For example, you could use the standard `psql` tool (preferably version 8.0.2) since Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2.

See: [Connect to Your Cluster by Using the psql Tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html)

So, your script would be something like:

```
psql -h clusterA -U username -d mydatabase -c 'UNLOAD...'
psql -h clusterB -U username -d mydatabase -c 'COPY...'
```

You could run this from AWS Lambda, but Lambda functions only run for a maximum of five minutes, and your script might exceed that limit. Instead, you could run a regular `cron` job on some machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although since you said that CLI is not relevant, but still if I can use, please let me know how to do that via CLI

Comment: You cannot use the AWS CLI to import/export data to Redshift. It is only used for commands issued to the AWS CLI. As a comparison, the AWS CLI can be used to launch EC2 instances, but if you wish to use some software *within* the instance, you have to communicate with the application directly. It's the same with Redshift.